# How to make synchronized rest API in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Here, I am using synchronized word because I didn't find that what should be the suitable word for this problem.

We have exposed an rest API to our client  which takes some parameters and which do something(also do some database operation here) if all mandatory parameters are available but while doing all these stuff sometimes I feel that if same request(if first request is already in process) is received more than once then there may be a chance of data in consistency.

**Example:**
Suppose we have an API which takes email or mobile then it checks that is there any user exist with this email or mobile or not?
If user not exist then we simply create a user(mapped email or mobile number into database)and show some other screen to user.
While checking user exist in the system if we received same request (with same mobile or email) simultaneously where if mapping is not done into database then there may be a chance that more than one user is created for same mobile or email which I don't want.

And sometimes we faced that issue. I will be very thankful so please someone give me the right way. How I can achieve that in Java?

Comment: Typically this is handled in the database by having unique constraints on the relevant columns. The first transaction to commit will succeed; the other one will get an error from the database (which you can catch in your java code if you want). Unless in some specific circumstances, I don't think you need to implement additional controls in java and can just rely on the database for this.

Comment: Hey brain99, i agree but we use no sql database(redis) which does not have this capability. When we discussed this problem with my friends and our senior colleague they suggest me that you can use any queue service(like JMS). will queue service is better solution for this problem? what you say?

Comment: How do you solve this problem then?